# Checking Identity Email token validity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a .net core application, where i make, after a register, an email token and i send it via email. 
The idea is, the user can come with that email token in the client app, and i want to check the validity of it (if it expired, if it's the right token associated with the given email).

I tried to find in userManager any method that i can use. What i found is `VerifyUserTokenAsync(ApplicationUser user, string tokenProvider, string purpose, string token)` but i don't know what to pass in the parameters.

So, can anyone help with the `tokenProvider` and `purpose`
I want to mention that the email token is generated with `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`. I can check the token with `ConfirmEmailAsync`, if the result isn't succeeded, the token is invalid, but i don't want to set EmailConfirmed to true if the token is valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A useful way to solve this problem is to look at the [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/Core/UserManager.cs) of `ConfirmEmailAsync`:

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ConfirmEmailAsync(TUser user, string token)
{
    // ...
    if (!await VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, Options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider, ConfirmEmailTokenPurpose, token))
    {
        return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.InvalidToken());
    }
    // ...
}
```

As might be expected, `ConfirmEmailAsync` makes a call to `VerifyUserTokenAsync`. The second and third parameters (`tokenProvider` and `purpose`) passed into this method are provided using properties of the `UserManager` class itself. Looking at the source again, it's clear that both `Options` and `ConfirmEmailTokenPurpose` are public:

```
public const string ConfirmEmailTokenPurpose = "EmailConfirmation";
// ...    
public IdentityOptions Options { get; set; }
```

Given all of this, you can call `VerifyUserTokenAsync` like so:

```
await userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(
    userYouAlreadyHave,
    userManager.Options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider,
    userManager.ConfirmEmailTokenPurpose,
    tokenYouAlreadyHave);
```

If this call returns `true`, the token is valid.